# How to rerun a script?

Tags: python, matplotlib, time, sleep

I have a function named plot(), which displays a graph with data in it. plot() takes it's data from a text file that is being updated every few seconds.

I want plot() to close the matplotlib window, and then run it again every t seconds.

What I have so far:

```
plot(t):
    draw plt
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(t)
    plt.close('all')

def rinse_repeat(t, total_time):
    while time.time < total_time
    plot()

rinse_repeat
```

How can I get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: What you have so far is a one big syntax error. Please post the actual code, not the one written while writing this question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Just make a loop that waits and counts seconds:

```
import time

def plot(t):
    draw plt
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(t)
    plt.close('all')

def rinse_repeat(t, total_time):
    seconds = 0
    while(seconds < total_time):
        time.sleep(t)
        seconds += t
        plot(10) # or whatever you want t to be
```

Comment: Sorry my syntax was a bit off in my question, The syntax was right in my code. Draw plt is just the psuedocode.

this is the error that is returned:
apparently time.time is not an integer
unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() <= int()